# How to disable new password Autofill feature in iOS 11 applications login screen?

Tags: ios11

I know iOS 11 Auto filling password is a very useful feature, but one of the client does not want this feature and he wants me to disable this. Can anyone, please help me how can I disable this feature?

Answer (score 4):

A very simple approach in ios11 worked for me. Suppose your IBOutlets are usernametextfield and passwordtextfield. In viewDidLoad() function of your viewcontroller that holds both outlets use the following code

```
   if #available(iOS 11, *) {
        // Disables the password autoFill accessory view.

        usernametextfield.textContentType = UITextContentType("")
        passwordtextfield.textContentType = UITextContentType("")
   }
```

Make sure you set up all of your UITextField objects like this. If you have for example a UITextField for the email address and another for password, then assign UITextContentType("") to both of their textContentType property. Otherwise, it will not work and the autoFill accessory view will still be shown.

Your question has already been answered under this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45452170/ios-11-disable-password-autofill-accessory-view-option) . 
Please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46474180/5866353) by @Bem and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46537857/5866353) by @Ammad.