# React Native - Disable Password AutoFill Option on iOS Keyboard

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, ios11, expo

In React Native, how do you disable or prevent the keyboard from displaying the Password Autofill accessory view option? There doesn't seem to be an property for **TextInput** that handles disabling this option. [React Native TextInput Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html). I am also using **Expo** on top of React Native.

[Password AutoFill was introduced in iOS 11](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/206/)

[Image of Password AutoFill Accessory view option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viAur.png)

Here is a post that has a solution for disabling the password autofill accessory, but how can we achieve this using React Native?

[iOS 11 disable password autofill accessory view option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45452170/ios-11-disable-password-autofill-accessory-view-option)

Comment: Have you tried `autoCompleteType: 'off'` ?

Comment: Password autofill is still shown with autoCompleteType: 'off'

Answer (score 10):

From RN docs:

> For iOS 11+ you can set textContentType to username or password to enable autofill of login details from the device keychain.

This means that setting **textContentType** to something different than username or password should disable autofill on iOS keyboard. But I noticed that setting **secureTextEntry** prop to true in the **TextInput** component also enables autofill even if **textContentType** is not username or password. This is true except for one particular case, when **textContentType** is set to **"oneTimeCode"**. This disables autofill even if **secureTextEntry** is true.

When I want to hide the password autofill and still set **secureTextEntry** to true, I just do this:

```
<TextInput
  secureTextEntry
  textContentType="oneTimeCode"
/>
```

There are other situations where **textContentType** is not **"username"** or **"password"** and **secureTextEntry** is false but autofill is still shown. Setting **textContentType** to **"oneTimeCode"** also works here.

```
<TextInput
  textContentType="oneTimeCode"
/>
```

This is more like a hack than a solution, but it works for me.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew there should be something to no allow the passwords autofill.

Answer (score 2):

I tried around and this helped me to disable autofill option:

```
<TextInput
  textContentType="none"
  autoCorrect={false}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, much better than using “otp” type

Answer (score 0):

**To disable autocomplete**

```
<Input autoCompleteType='off' placeholder="Email" />
```