# iOS Passwords autofill accessory view makes app get stuck

Tags: ios, ios12

I have and app on the app store. I uploaded a new version which was **rejected**. 
why? 
After the login screen there's a Terms & Conditions page and it seemed to be **not responsive** for the person who tested the app. I snuffed around, updated my testing device to iOS 12 and saw that on the login screen, when either email or password textField is selected, "Passwords" autofill accessory view pops up above the keyboard. When the user taps on that button nothing happens and the app really becomes unresponsive, just absoulutly stuck. When you exit the app and comes back again the app is responsive again and also, the console outputs the error:

```
Keyboard cannot present view controllers (attempted to present <UIKeyboardHiddenViewController_Autofill: 0x10e4227c0>)
```

[image]

I tried to disable passwords autofill accessory view as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45452170/ios-11-disable-password-autofill-accessory-view-option). But it's not working on iOS 12.

Well who am I to decide, but I think it's a *bug* on the iOS 12.

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

Managed to solve this issue by preventing iOS 12 to recognise the password textField as a password textField, which made the password accessory view to not be presented at all. 
Answered fully [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45452170/ios-11-disable-password-autofill-accessory-view-option/52427015#52427015):