# How to hide icon and text password above keyboard in iphone 6s and 5s

Tags: javascript, react-native

My screen have 3 `TextInput`: email, re email and password. Here is my code:

```js
 render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TextInput
                    placeholder="Mail Address"
                    onSubmitEditing={() => { this.remail.focus(); }}
                    keyboardType={"email-address"}
                    blurOnSubmit={false}
                />
                <TextInput
                    secureTextEntry={false}
                    ref={(input) => { this.remail = input; }}
                    keyboardType={"email-address"}
                    onSubmitEditing={() => { this.password.focus(); }}
                    placeholder="Enter the mail address again"
                />
                <TextInput
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    ref={(input) => { this.password = input; }}
                    placeholder="Password"
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
```

When `TextInput` re email focus have a icon and text password above keyboard like photo:
[image]

How I can hide it when `TextInput` `remail` focus?
p/s : it only show in Iphone 5s and 6s, Iphone 6 and 5 don't show icon and text above keyboard
Thank you!

Comment: have you tried `autocomplete='off' ` ?

Comment: @ShivKumarBaghel yep but it have same result. I question in group and have the answer it will show in Iphone 12.

Comment: Check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45452170/ios-11-disable-password-autofill-accessory-view-option

Comment: use  `autocomplete="off"` `autocorrect="off"`

Answer (score 0):

remove secureTextEntry={false} 
from

```
               <TextInput
                    secureTextEntry={false}
                    ref={(input) => { this.remail = input; }}
                    keyboardType={"email-address"}
                    onSubmitEditing={() => { this.password.focus(); }}
                    placeholder="Enter the mail address again"
                />
```

Comment: Initially I did not add it but it not working so I added it and same value