# Getting strong password on not necessary field in iOS 12

Tags: ios, ios12

I've created signup form and applied logic for strong password and auto fill options.
i.e. first name, last name, email and strong password.
I have one more field in sign up for named "Referral code" which is optional.
I've given "New Password" content type to 'password' field, and "Unspecified" to 'referral code' field.
but when filling form, I'm getting strong password filled in password and referral code field both.
I don't want to fill password in referral code field.
Here are screenshots for better understanding.
[image: with and without strong password filled]
How can I prevent them?

Comment: Try reading from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45452170/ios-11-disable-password-autofill-accessory-view-option

Comment: Already tried to set OneTimeCode, setting email and other type will be wrong

Comment: Are you using any textfield libraries?

Comment: no, @Sagarkoyani

Comment: add your code in question.

Comment: I think, I didn't wrote any code for using strong password, if you want I can add Interface Builder's screeenshot. That's why I didn't add tag for swift or objective-c