# Disable Strong Password yellow highlight in ReactNative TextInput field for iOS when secureTextEntry is used

Tags: ios, react-native

How can I disable the password autofill feature in iOS 12 and higher in ReactNative TextInput when secureTextEntry is used.
From searching in SO i have found some workaround likely-

```
blurOnSubmit={false}
onSubmitEditing={()=> Keyboard.dismiss()}`
and textContentType='oneTimeCode' //or textContentType='none'
```

but this issue keeps appearing.
Can anyone guide me through this to solve the problem in ReactNative side.
**Also I have found solution for native iOS side but i don't know how to do it for ReactNative**, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45452170/ios-11-disable-password-autofill-accessory-view-option) the link.

*Image*

[image: Password autofill]