# Disable yellow box in password input react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, input, passwords, react-native-elements

I have a form including multiple inputs and multiple types in my react native app. two of them are passwords. in simulator when i'm filling the inputs after I click the password input it change to yellow and disable itself. notice that sometimes it doesn't happen
its react native expo app and input come from react-native-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
secureTextEntry={true}
textContentType="oneTimeCode"
```

Check out this ref [Link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45452170/ios-11-disable-password-autofill-accessory-view-option) and [Github-issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21911)

Answer (score 1):

use `secureTextEntry={true}`inside input tag

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
Please note that this is already mentioned by another answer. If you have nothing to elaborate please consider deleting this answer.