# iOS TextField Strong password autofill, even if we don't want it

Tags: ios, swiftui, autofill, securefield

I am using two textField `password` & `confirmPassword`

***My iCloud Keychain is turned On.***

```
  @State private var email: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    @State private var passwordConfirmation: String = ""
   
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 16) {
                TextField("Email address", text: $email)
                SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                    .textContentType(.password)
                SecureField("Password confirmation", text: $passwordConfirmation)
                    .textContentType(.password)
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 32)
            .padding(.horizontal, 16)
        }
    }
```

When I tap on the password secure field, iOS show me the strong password view :

[image]

If I use this feature, everything is working fine, but if I tap on "Other options..." then "Choose my own password":

[image]

The textfields are cleared (that's great), but if I tap on the email textfield (or any other textfields), the password secure field is filled with the strong password that I've just said I don't want...

Here is a video :

[image]

I tried couple of approaches like. `first.contentType = .newPassword and second.contentType = .password` or use `.newPassword` for both but does not works.

Bug reference: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/716589

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45452170/ios-11-disable-password-autofill-accessory-view-option does this work ?   `.disableAutocorrection(true) `

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya no it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

```
.textContentType(.none)
```

this will disable autofill