# How to hide input accessory view?

Tags: swift, inputaccessoryview

I have a segmented control in my application where one of the tabs is a chat controller.
I'm using the input accessory view for the toolbar that has the send button and the textfield. 
The problem is i can't hide the input accessory view while switching tabs

I tried hiding it, removing it and adjusting the collection view bottom constraint accordingly when it's hidden or not but that didn't work

```
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView 
{
    return inputContainerView  
}


override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572649/how-to-hide-inputaccessoryview-without-dismissing-keyboard

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide inputAccessoryView without dismissing keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572649/how-to-hide-inputaccessoryview-without-dismissing-keyboard)